# How to ignore slicer for particular measure?

Tags: powerbi, dax

My data is

[image]
I'd like to block measure (sum of amount) with one filter Choose = "Home"

[image]

When I change slicer on "Not Home" my data change.

[image]

I don't want it. When I click "Not home" I want to have same values like I click "Home"

I can't use Edit interactions because I want to add new columns that they will be depended to slicer. I'd like to apply it to only one maesure.

I tried calculate(sum(amount), filter(choose = "Home").
It doesn't work.
Data still change.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this work?

```
Sum of Amount = 
CALCULATE ( 
    SUM ( 'Table'[Amount] ),
    'Table'[Choose] = "Home"
)
```

I think in your original measure you forgot `ALL ( 'Table'[Choose] )`. The above measure is semantically identical to:

```
Sum of Amount = 
CALCULATE ( 
    SUM ( 'Table'[Amount] ),
    FILTER ( 
        ALL ( 'Table'[Choose] ) ,
        'Table'[Choose] = "Home"
    )
)
```

I don't have a Windows box to test this simple model, but perhaps you also need to invoke `KEEPFILTERS`:

```
Sum of Amount = 
CALCULATE ( 
    SUM ( 'Table'[Amount] ),
    KEEPFILTERS ( 'Table'[Choose] = "Home" )
)
```